# Socket.io: set/get vs simple var

Tags: node.js, socket.io

In socket.io you can store and fetch data associated with a particular client using socket.set and socket.get methods. However, you can simply declare a var inside `on.('connection')` event handler and it will work just the same way as set/get if the MemoryStore is used. What's the difference then? Do get/set make sense only when RedisStore is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.get` , `.set` makes sense when you need to associate a variable & a value with a particular `socket` object, you can do what you are saying by playing with scope, but remember no matter the place that `socket.io` stores data, it doesn't mess with your function scopes.

In a simple example, say you want to store a name,email address, you would declare then inside `.on('connection',..)` in the form of

```
var connnection={
 socket_id123:{
  "name":"joe"
  ,"mail":"joe@ii.com"
 }
 ,socket_id234:{
  "name":"joe"
  ,"mail":"joe@ii.com"
 }
}
```

in this form , you have to check for existense, query the object, and keep track of data, so you can mess with the tree structure.

while with `.get`,`.set` the above checking and manipulating the tree, is simplified, each socket object has its own variables, and nothing can overwrite them, delete, or mess with them, and keeps the scope cleaner.